# Goodness of Fit test for Logistic Regression Model

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

Data have been collected for 176 students. The response variable is 'Choice of Career' having 2 categories namely 'Academic' and 'Non-academic'. I have taken two explanatory variables namely 'Gender'(Having 2 levels) and 'Satisfaction Level with the subject' (Having 3 levels). Now, I have used the software Minitab 16 for this work. The software calculates the Pearson statistic based on Pearson residuals. It displays that the statistic has 2 degrees of freedom.

Now, I couldn't understand that how did it calculate that degrees of freedom for my data. So, can anyone guide me how to calculate the degrees of freedom of this Pearson statistic for the data set mentioned above?

Comment: I would not use Pearson residuals, and I don't think this really has a chi-square distribution.  I suggest using directed tests, e.g., add nonlinear terms in a continuous predictor to check for linearity.  Better: if sample size allows just allow everything to be nonlinear but force smoothness.  Details in my RMS [book and course notes](http://fharrell.com/links).